# How to include ColdFusion code but not have it processed?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cffile

I am using ColdFusion 8.

I am creating some code that will create a folder and insert a file.  The file will be tweaked later by a human.

I create the directory like this:

```
<cfdirectory action="create" directory="#LOCAL.PathToCreate#">
```

Next, I need to create a file with the name of index.cfm.  Right now, the content that needs to go into the index.cfm file is within Test-21-index.txt. I create the content like this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="LOCAL.MyContent">
    <cfinclude template="Test-21-index.txt">
</cfsavecontent>
<cffile action="write" file="#NewTreatmentPath##LOCAL.NewFile#" output="#LOCAL.MyContent#" nameconflict="overwrite">
```

The content of Test-21-index.txt has ColdFusion code in it.  The problem that I am encountering is that when I include the file Test-21-index.txt, the ColdFusion code is being run.

How do I get the code to be created as a text file that is NOT run during the creation of the file?

UPDATE ~ With so many tools available to implement my solution, I just needed the right combination.  Instead of reading the file, using cfsavecontent, and then writing the file, I merely copied the file.  Ugh.  That was way too easy.

```
<cffile action="copy" source="#CurrentDirectory#\#LOCAL.FileToInclude#" destination="#NewTreatmentPath#\#LOCAL.NewFile#">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using `cfinclude`, you can use `cffile` to read the file and then output its contents in the `cfsavecontent` tag:

```
<cffile action="read" file="test-21-index.txt" variable="fileContent" />

<cfsavecontent variable="LOCAL.MyContent">
   <cfoutput>#filecontent#</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<!--- or even <cfset LOCAL.MyContent = fileContent /> --->

<cffile action="write" file="#NewTreatmentPath##LOCAL.NewFile#" output="#LOCAL.MyContent#" nameconflict="overwrite">
```

Code is untested, but I think it should work. I believe you will need to work out the path to `test-21-index.txt` a little differently, though.

Comment: Why do you need the cfsavecontent when you already have #filecontent#? It's redundant.

Comment: @NathanStrutz You don't if that's all that needs to go into the output file. I wasn't sure if Evik's code was a simplified example (i.e. needing more stuff to go into the output file), so I left it as untouched as possible.

Comment: I'd also add that if all you're doing is reading the contents of the file and writing it to another file, then you could just use the "copy" action of CFFILE and bypass reading/writing the contents entirely and reduce it down to one line and save some processing time as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, using CFFILE and copy was exactly what I needed.